# HTML element wont stay positioned at bottom

Tags: html, css

So I have a chat UI that is a box where messages go, and at the bottom of the box of messages is a text input element. It works fine at the beginning, but once enough messages appear then the text input element scrolls up, along with the messages, and will not stay positioned at the bottom. How can I do this? Any useful thoughts would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="chatui">
<div id="chatmsgs"></div>
<input type="text" id="chatbox">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#chatui {
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
    margin-left:5px;
    overflow:auto;
    }
#chatbox {bottom:3px;position:absolute;width:378px;}
#chatmsgs {position:absolute;}
```

Here is my Javascript:

This just says when you press "Enter" on your keyboard to display the text you typed into the "chatmsgs" div.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
if (document.activeElement.id == 'chatbox') {
var msg = document.getElementById('chatbox').value;
document.getElementById('chatbox').value = '';  
var ms = '<p>'+msg+'</p>';
$('#chatmsgs').append(ms);
}
}
});
```

Check out this fiddle to see what I am talking about:
https://jsfiddle.net/ev3uymw6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `overflow:auto` and appropriate `height` to the `chatmsgs` div, so that it doesn't grow beyond the size of `chatui` and make it scroll alltogether.

```js
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (document.activeElement.id == 'chatbox') {
      var msg = document.getElementById('chatbox').value;
      document.getElementById('chatbox').value = '';
      var ms = '<p>' + msg + '</p>';
      $('#chatmsgs').append(ms);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#chatui {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid #8AC007;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#chatbox {
  bottom: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 378px;
}
#chatmsgs {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 378px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="chatui">
    <div id="chatmsgs">
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="chatbox">
  </div>
</body>
```